# MySQL : LEFT JOIN question, returns too many records

Tags: mysql, json, left-join

I got the following shema in MySQL

Table "**items**"

```
+--------+--------+-------------+
|item_id | name   | description |
+--------+--------+-------------+
|1       | Item 1 | Fist item   |
+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Table "**items_relations**"

```
+-----+---------+----------+
|id   | item_id | child_id |
+-----+---------+----------+
|1    | 1       | 1        |
+-----+---------+----------+
|2    | 1       | 2        |
+-----+---------+----------+
```

Table "**children**"

```
+------------+-------+--------+
|children_id | color | weight |
+------------+-------+--------+
|1           | blue  | 5      |
+------------+-------+--------+
|2           | red   | NULL   |
+------------+-------+--------+
```

Table "**comments**"

```
+-----------+-----------+----------------+
|comment_id | parent_id | comment        |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+
|1          | 1         | Blablabla      |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+
|2          | 1         | Bliblibli      |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

With that, I want to return via a SQL query the following data:

- item_id
- name
- description
- number of comments
- children data in JSON format

Here is what I am doing but the JSON data looks multiplied by the number of rows or comments or children

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.name, i.description, count(comment_id) as nb_comm,
CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('','{"color":"', color, '", "weight":"', weight,'"}')), ']') as data
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.parent_id = i.item_id
LEFT JOIN items_relations ir ON ir.item_id = i.item_id
LEFT JOIN children ch ON ir.child_id = ch.children_id
WHERE 1
```

Data fiels contains

```
[{"color":"blue", "weight":"5"},{"color":"blue", "weight":"5"},{"color":"red", "weight":"10"},{"color":"red", "weight":"10"}]
```

What can I do for having the correct content in the data field?

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45b680/2)

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: It's actually MariaDB 10.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use DISTINCT for GROUP_CONCAT   and COUNT

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.name, i.description, count(distinct comment_id) as nb_comm,
CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('','{"color":"', color, '", "weight":"', weight,'"}')), ']') as data
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.parent_id = i.item_id
LEFT JOIN items_relations ir ON ir.item_id = i.item_id
LEFT JOIN children ch ON ir.child_id = ch.children_id
GROUP BY i.item_id, i.name, i.description
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45b680/13

Comment: Yes ! That solves the data issue, but the number of comments is still wrong.